# TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not tuple

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to read multiple images from a folder and copy it to another folder. I'm able to select multiple images but when I press File open button the above error occurs

```
import shutil,os,glob

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames
def callback():
    src = askopenfilenames()
    des = r"C:\Users\tkumar\.spyder-py3\there"
    sourceFiles = os.listdir(src)  #error is here i think.
    #print(len(sourceFiles))
    #shutil.copy(src, des)
    try:
        for fileName in sourceFiles:
            fullName = os.path.join(src, fileName)
            if (os.path.isfile(fullName)):
                shutil.copy(fullName, des)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error %s" %e)

errmsg = 'Error!'
Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill=X)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you look at the output of `src = askopenfilenames()`? Also, why do you have `#error is here i think.` and not the actual traceback so we can see exactly what causes the issue?

Comment: What's not clear about this error message? `askopenfilenames()` returned a tuple, you passed it to `os.listdir`, but this function doesn't work with tuples, so you got the error.

Comment: Read up on [`os.listdir(path='.')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir). Probably, you need [`askdirectory`](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#dialogs) instead.

Comment: tup= askopenfilenames()
  
    src =" ".join(tup)
now it gives the following error

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tkumar\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\tkumar\.spyder-py3\fol_img.py", line 22, in callback
    sourceFiles = os.listdir(src)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:/Users/tkumar/.spyder-py3/here/pyc.png'

Comment: Thanks man , askdirectory worked for me

Answer (score 0):

````
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu May 14 16:19:47 2020

@author: tkumar
"""
"""
This block of code moves images from one folder(source) to another (destination))
"""
import shutil,os,glob

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
def callback():
    #src =''
    tup= askdirectory()
    src= filedialog.askdirectory()
   # src =" ".join(tup) 
    print("------------",type(src))


    #des=''
    des= r"C:\Users\tkumar\.spyder-py3\there"
    sourceFiles = os.listdir(src)
    #print(len(sourceFiles))
    #shutil.copy(src, des)

    try:
        for fileName in sourceFiles:
            fullName = os.path.join(src, fileName)
            if (os.path.isfile(fullName)):
                shutil.copy(fullName, des)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error %s" %e)

errmsg = 'Error!'
Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill=X)
mainloop() ```
````